# unable to close due to unfinalised statements in android

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I recieve an error while using sqlite in android...

```
    E/AppUncaughtExceptionHandler( 1820): UncaughtException occurred!!
E/AppUncaughtExceptionHandler( 1820): Stack Trace is the following
W/System.err( 1820): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to close due to unfinalised statements
W/System.err( 1820):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbclose(Native Method)
```

if anyone have any idea then please let me know.

Comment: whats the SQL statement that you used it on the app ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the cursor.

For Example:

```
public String getName(String id) throws SQLException{
String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ItemID, KEY_NAME};
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ItemID + "='" + id + "'", null, null, null, null);
if(c != null){
    c.moveToFirst();
    String name = c.getString(1);
    c.close();
    return name;
}
return null;
```

}

CURSOR.CLOSE() is what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem with an error like this is that there is a selection that happened that returned a large number of rows but somehow was not utilized or exhausted.
eg.

```
query1 = conn.execute("select id, url, description from customer \
                      where first_name=?", (i,)) 
data=query1.fetchone() #I only want to know the existence of one row
If data is None:
    conn.close()
```

query1 might have returned a million rows that has not been processed. I think that this is what it meant by 'unfinalised'!
To avoid the error, I closed the query first before closing the database.
ie

```
If data is None:
    query1.close()
    conn.close()
```